# Loop Through IP Address Range to Check Printer Status in HTML - Python & BeuatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a few IP addresses which are printer to make sure the status is READY and I'm not sure my code is actually looping through each one. The code should print Status: READY the first time the code runs then after every 2 mins it will check again if nothing changed then it will print "Nothing Changed" otherwise it will print the Status.

```
# Scale1 Ticket Printer 10.56.32.247
# Scale2 Ticket Printer 10.56.32.248
# Scale3 Ticket Printer 10.56.32.246

import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def main():
    result = []
    for ip in range(246, 248):
        resp = requests.get(f"http://10.56.32.%d" % ip)
        result.extend(resp)
        txt = resp.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')
        status = soup.find_all('h3')[0].text
        return status


res_before = ""
while True:
    res = main()
    if res != res_before:
        #print(res)
        res_before = res

    else:
        print("nothing changed")

        for i in range(120):
            msg = "Pausing for 2 minutes..."
            sys.stdout.write("\r{} {} seconds ".format(msg, i))
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

The first time the code runs it should print **Status: READY** but it's just printing nothing changed.
Here are the results from the code. Thank you in advanced for any help it's much appreciated.

```
nothing changed
Pausing for 2 minutes... 119 seconds nothing changed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return e.g. a dict with a key/value for each IP address.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


def get_statuses():
    results = {}
    for ip in range(246, 248):
        resp = requests.get(f"http://10.56.32.%d" % ip)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            results[ip] = f"Error {resp.status_code}"
        else:
            txt = resp.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "lxml")
            results[ip] = soup.find_all("h3")[0].text
    return results


def main():
    old_statuses = None
    while True:
        new_statuses = get_statuses()
        if old_statuses != new_statuses:
            print("Status:", new_statuses)
        old_statuses = new_statuses
        print("Checking again in 2 minutes.")
        time.sleep(120)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To print only changed statuses, you could do something like

```
old_statuses = {}
while True:
    new_statuses = get_statuses()
    for key, value in new_statuses.items():
        if value != old_statuses.get(key):
            print("Changed:", key, value)
    old_statuses = new_statuses
```

And further, to give a name to each machine, make a mapping out of them.

```
addresses = {
  "Scale1": "http://10.56.32.247/",
  "Scale2": "http://10.56.32.248/",
  "Scale3": "http://10.56.32.246/",
}

def get_statuses():
    results = {}
    for name, address in addresses.items():
        resp = requests.get(address)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            results[name] = f"Error {resp.status_code}"
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
            results[name] = soup.find_all("h3")[0].text
    return results
```

Comment: This seems to work good thank you so much. Is it possible that if a status has changed to just print the status for that printer like 246 or 247? Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I hate to ask but how can I rename 246 to "Scale1" and 247 to "Scale2"
Changed: 246 Status: READY
Changed: 247 Status: READY
Changed: 248 Status: READY

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help. I'm just an IT Manager but I find Python to be very useful so I'm trying to learn a bit. Thanks again.